# Angular and Clicking on List Items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand why when I click on this list item it doesn't want to go to its corresponding page. Instead it reverts back to the main page.

```
<li ng-click="goToPage('#/show-schedule')">Schedule</li>

angular
.module('CaliforniaJam', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'simplePagination',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngTouch',
    //'mobile-angular-ui'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/show-schedule', {
            templateUrl: 'views/show-schedule.html',
            controller: 'ShowScheduleCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ShowScheduleCtrl'
         .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });
});


$scope.goToPage = function(url) {
        $rootScope.transition('slide', 'left', url);
    }
```

Comment: share body of goToPage() function

Comment: Check updated post.

Comment: What happens when you directly hit the /show-schedule url on browser?

Comment: remove the # from start of url, it doesn't need that @user3732216